# How to change background Color of label full length when Mouse Hover in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't Select label back Ground color  Mouse Hover event in full length,only can select The Word length

[image]

**I would like to get log out background same like *username* background as full width**

```
private void label5_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.LblChange.BackgroundImage = null;
    this.LblChange.BackgroundImage = global::Flex.Properties.Resources.Mail1;
    this.LblChange.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    this.LblChange.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    !
}
```

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: would you please write in detail. your question is ambiguous.

Comment: I have just add my code, unfortunately I am unable to add screenshot until I get at least 10 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select the label then goto autosize and set it to false... then increase the length of the label as much as you want... then apply your above code... it'll work.. All the best...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `label5` color:

```
private void label5_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ...
  label5.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  ...
}
```

or alternatively you need to define `LblChange` Mouse hover event:

```
private void LblChange_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           ....
                this.LblChange.BackColor = Color.Blue;
           ...
}
```

Comment: both are giving same result

Comment: The problem was basically changing the width of the label.